# how to use Javascript for slide left

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i have use the javascript for sliding the element up and down as fallow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var $divSlide = $("div.slide");
            $divSlide.hide().eq(0).show();
            var panelCnt = $divSlide.length;

            setInterval(panelSlider, 3000);

            function panelSlider() {
                $divSlide.eq(($divSlide.length++) % panelCnt)
                .slideUp("slow", function () {

                    $divSlide.eq(($divSlide.length) % panelCnt)
                        .slideDown("slow");

                });
            }
        });
     </script>
```

which slide the panel up and down having slide tag panals are added as fallow

```
 //protion
            DataTable promo = SQl.ExecuteSelectCommand("select Promo_Code,Promo_Discription,Promo_Min_Ammount,Persent_Off,Start_Date,End_Date,Supp_Name from Prommosion_Details_View ");
            if (promo.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= promo.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    Panel p = new Panel();
                    p.CssClass = "slide";
                    PromoUC PUC = (PromoUC)Page.LoadControl("PromoUC.ascx");
                    PUC.setText(promo.Rows[i][3].ToString(), promo.Rows[i][1].ToString(), promo.Rows[i][4].ToString(), promo.Rows[i][5].ToString(), promo.Rows[i][0].ToString(), " From " + promo.Rows[i]["Supp_Name"].ToString());
                    p.Controls.Add(PUC);
                    searchBoxPromoPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(p);
                }
            }
```

above code is working fine but the problem is tat i have to scroll it left and right with elastic effect

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) which helps you to do any animation effect.
you can animate any css property,in your case the width could fit your needs.check the examples online.